# How to pupulate nested DB without hurting encapsulation?

Tags: database, oop, encapsulation

I have the following situation (code is python, but this is not language specific):

I need to populate a tabular DB in a way equivalent to:

```
for i,a in enumerate(as):
    for j,b in enumerate(a.bs):
        for k,c in enumerate(b.cs):
            db[i,j,k] = c.data()
```

This method forces c to publish its private Data, thus breaking its encapsulation.

I am aware some of this chain could be replaced by `a.update_db`, `b.update_db` and so on, but still at the very least, c would still have to allow access to its private data.

---

Another way to tackle this would be to allow C to update the DB like so:

```
for i,a in enumerate(as):
    for j,b in enumerate(a.bs):
        for k,c in enumerate(b.cs):
            c.update_db_at(i,j,k)
```

Which would make C know i,j,k which it shouldn't really care about, and C's responsibility isn't anything about updating the DB, but rather representing some object.

---

This looks like a very common problem to me, and i'm sure there is some standard best practice for this.

**What is a good way to populate a nested DB from a corresponding nested object structure that doesn't break encapsulation?**

Comment: Somehow you need to get the information from class C, right? What would be the point of it otherwise?